# Magento decimal quantity stock management

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm confused about how to deal with Magento stock management for produts selled through decimal quantity.

Imagine that I want to sell a product based on their weight, rice for example. I want that my customers would be able to buy decimal qty (1kg, 0.9kg). 
The problem is: how do I manage stock? At this time I've created a simple product with weight equals '1' and I'd manage my stock through the inventory tab. Is this approach right?

Also, I need to be able to make this product as part of another ones (Grouped product). I mean, sell (for example) a package with three different kinds of rice and when I sell this group the stock amount of eache product should decrease as well.

Thanks!

Ps: I'm using Magento 1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is possible in magento. Magento have default option for specify quantity with decimal points, you just enable the Qty Uses Decimals -> yes in the inventory section of product page in admin.

Comment: I answered with referernce of this blog http://www.webinse.com/blog/magento/decimal-products/

Comment: it's better adding reference in answer not in comment

Comment: Ok. Next time i will to like that. thanks @ShreeKrishna